# How to insert a formfeed into a text file, using Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

It a simple problem.

I need to insert formfeed characters into a text file:

- ASCII 12/0xC
- CONTROL-L
- U+000C

I've not been able to figure out how to do this in Sublime text 3.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal value for the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) form feed character is 12. If you're using Sublime with Microsoft Windows, hold down the <ALT> key and type the characters "12" on the numeric keypad. This will insert the "♀" character in to your document.

You can also copy the "♀" character from this answer and paste it in to your document as well.

Comment: "♀" is U+2640 "Female Sign".  Not sure why the cmd window outputs that for a form feed.